# Problem with access Couchbase from python on Centos 7

Tags: python, couchbase, centos7

I try to access couchbase's bucket from `python`.
I installed on my Centos 7 packge such was described in this documentation:

> https://docs.couchbase.com/c-sdk/2.10/relnotes-c-sdk.html
>   https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/2.5/start-using-sdk.html

`couchbase-2.5.1` module was successfull installed, but
`import couchbase` entails this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/couchbase/**init**.py", line 31, in module
>       from typing import Callable, Any, Union, NewType, Mapping, List
>   ImportError: No module named typing

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Try `sudo pip3 install typing`

Answer (score 1):

The `typing` module was introduced to offer PEP484 annotations to our API users. Unfortunately, although most recent Python 2.7 and 3.x versions come bundled with this, a few older versions do not. Our apologies for this oversight.

Installing the `typing` module from PyPi will fix this for now, but we have a permanent fix for this here:

https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/PYCBC-554

This will be in the next release of the Python Client (2.5.2).

Hope that helps.

Ellis